# OpenCL kernel out of resources based on number of loop iterations INSIDE the kernel. Can the compiled kernel be too large to fit on the GPU?

Tags: memory, gpu, opencl

**TL;DR** I have an OpenCL kernel that loops for a large number of iterations and calls several user-made functions. The kernel works fine for few iterations, but increasing the number of iterations causes an `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES (-5)` error. If the same kernel is executed on a better GPU it is able to loop for more iterations without the error. What can be causing this error based on the number of iterations? Is it possible that the loops are being unrolled and generating a coder larger than the GPU can hold?

I am developing an OpenCL kernel to run on GPU that computes a very complex function. To keep things organized, I have a "kernel.cl" file with the main kernel (the __kernel void function) and a "aux_functions.cl" file with ~20 auxiliary functions (they are of type int, int2, int16, **but not __kernel**) that are called several times by the kernel and by themselves.

**The problem specification is roughly as follows (justification for such many loops):**

- I have two arrays representing full HD images (1920x1080 integers)
- For each 128x128 patch of one image, I must find the value of 4 parameters that optimize a given function (the second image is used to evaluate how good it is)
- For the same 128x128 patch and the same 4 parameters, each 4x4 sub-patch is transformed slightly different based on its position inside the larger 128x128 patch

**And I tried to model the execution as follows:**

- Each workgroup will compute the kernel for one 128x128 patch (I started processing only the 10 first patches -- 10 workgroups)
- Each workgroup is composed of 256 workitems
- Each workitem will test a distinct set of values (a fraction of a predefiend set) for the 4 parameters based on their IDs

**The main structure of the kernel is as follows:**

```
__kernel void funct(__global int *referenceFrameSamples, __global int *currentFrameSamples,const int frameWidth, const int frameHeight, __global int *result){
// Initialize some variables and get global and local IDs
  for(executed X times){ // These 4 outer loops are used to test different combinations of parameters to be applied in a given function in the inner loops
    for(executed Y times){
      for(executed Z times){
        for(executed W times){
          // Simple assignments based on the outer for loops
          for(executed 32x){ // Each execution of the inner loop applies a function to a 4x4 patch
            for(executed 32x){
              // The relevant computation is performed here
              // Calls a couple of lightweight functions using only the private variables
              // Calls a complex function that uses the __global int *referenceFrameSamples variable

            }
          }
          // Compute something and use select() to update the best value
       }
     }
  }
// Write the best value to __global *results buffer
}
```

**The problem is that** when the outer 4 loops are repeated a few times the kernel runs fine, but if I increase the iterations the kernel crashes with the error `ERROR! clWaitForEvents returned CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES (-5)`. I am testing it on a notebook with a GPU GeForce 940MX with 2GB, and the kernel starts crashing when X * Y * Z * W = 1024.

The `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` call has no error, only the `clWaitForEvents()` called after it returns an error. I am using **CLIntercept** to profile the errors and running time of the kernel. Also, when the kernel runs smooth I can measure the execution time correctly (showed next), but when it crashes, the "measured" execution time is ridiculously wrong (billions of miliseconds) even though it crashes on the first seconds.

```
cl_ulong time_start;
cl_ulong time_end;
clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
double nanoSeconds = time_end-time_start;
printf("OpenCl Execution time is: %0.3f miliseconds \n",nanoSeconds / 1000000.0);
```

**What I tested:**

- Improve the complex auxiliary function that used __global variable: instead of passing the __global pointer, I read the relevant part of the array into a private array and passed it as argument. Outcome: improved running time on success cases, but still fails in the same case
- Reduce workgroups and workitems: even using 1 workgroup and 1 workitem (the absolute minimum) with the same number of iterations yields the same error. For a smaller number of iterations, running time decreases with less workitems/groups
- Running the same kernel on a better GPU: after doing the previous 2 modifications (improved function and reduced workitems) I launched the kernel on a desktop equipped with a GPU Titan V with 12GB. It is able to compute the kernel with a larger number of iterations (I tried up to 1 million iterations) without giving the `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES`, and the running time seems to increase linearly with the iterations. Although this is the computer that will actually run the kernel over a dataset to solve my problem, it is a server that must be accessed remotely. I would prefer to do the development on my notebook and deploy the final code on the server.

**My guess:** I know that function calls are inlined in GPU. Since the program is crashing based on the number of iterations, my only guess is that these for loops are being unrolled, and with the inlined functions, the compiled kernel is too big to fit on the GPU (even with a single  workitem). This also explains why using a better GPU allows increasing the number of iterations.

**Question:** What could be causing this CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES error based on the number of iterations?

Of course I could reduce the number of iterations in each workitem, but then I would need multiple workgroups to process the same set of data (the same 128x128 patch) and would need to access global memory to select the best result between workgroups of the same patch. I may end up proceeding in this direction, but I would really like to know what is happening with the kernel at this moment.

**Update** after @doqtor comment:
Using `-cl-nv-verbose`  when building the program reports the following resources usage. It's strange that these values do not change irrespective of the number of iterations, either when the program runs successfully and when it crashes.

```
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem, 532 bytes cmem[3]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'naive_affine_2CPs_CU_128x128_SR_64x64' for 'sm_50'
ptxas info    : Function properties for naive_affine_2CPs_CU_128x128_SR_64x64
ptxas         .     66032 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 140 registers, 360 bytes cmem[0]
```

Running `clinfo` reports that my GPU has

```
Registers per block (NV)    65536
Global memory size          2101870592 (1.958GiB)
Max memory allocation       525467648 (501.1MiB)
Local memory size           49152 (48KiB)
```

It seems that I am not using too many registers, but I don't know how those `stack frame`, `cmem[0]` and `cmem[3]` relate to the memory information reported by `clinfo`.

Comment: Have you tried passing `-cl-nv-verbose` to get more detailed output of the resources usage?

Comment: I tried using this flag and updated the question (at the end) with the results @doqtor. Do you know how those values relate to the memory information reported by clinfo?

Comment: _It's strange that these values do not change irrespective of the number of iterations, either when the program runs successfully and when it crashes._ Then I would check if that's not a watchdog problem - more iterations means longer time to process which may kick on the watchdog.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that the loops are being unrolled and generating a coder larger than the GPU can hold?

Yes, that is part of the problem. The compiler sees that you have a loop with a fixed, small range, and it automatically unrolls it. This happens for the six nested loops and then the assembly blows up. This will get register spilling into global memory which makes the application very slow.
However even if the compiler does not unroll the loops, every thread does `X*Y*Z*W*32*32` iterations of "The relevant computation", which takes an eternety. The system thinks it freezed up and you get `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` .

Can you really not parallelize any of these six nested loops? The best solution would be to parallelize them all, that means include them in the kernel range and launch a few hundred million threads that do "The relevant computation" without any loops. You should have as much independent threads / workgroups as possible to get the best performance (saturate the GPU).

Remember, your GPU has thousands of cores grouped into warps of 32 and SMs of 2 or 4 warps, and if you only launch a single workgroup, it will run on only a single SM with 64 or 128 cores and the remaining cores stay idle.